# Error opening .wmv file

Tags: 12.04, wmv

I tried to open a .wmv file in Thunderbird. I was asked to download files in order to have it accessible. At the end of the installation `An error occurred - Location not found.` error message displayed with just the OK button available. Now when I press the Play button just the error message displays so I am not sure which packages need to be installed/uninstalled.

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 (32-bit) with open-jdk-7.

Error was generated when installing:

```
GStreamer ffmpeg video plugin
```

It seemed that it took a while to have the process completing all steps of the download / install before the error message displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I started from scratch and this time the download/install worked just fine.  The .wmv file could be opened inside Thunderbird.

Comment: I edited my original question. Regarding the actual answer I just posted what really happened: worked fine in the second attempt. Perhaps some hiccup with my wireless connection during the first download???